# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, servidor, get, objetos

Tentei voltar a página usando backup para resolver o problema mas não consigo. Subo a página e ela continua com o mesmo erro, não sei como faço para resolver. Se caso tenha alguma forma mais facil como algo para que o servidor reconheça as atualizações dos arquivos por exemplo talvez seja mais fácil de resolver. Pois colocaria novamente o arquivo de backup da página com problema. Se alguém puder também me ajudar dando um direcionamento de onde pode estar vindo esse problema.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeE12.png)

Ao lado da aparece essa lista:

28. ErrorException
    …/­app/­storage/­views/­e4eb13e60cfc4ad016623c6d6306139d3
29. Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine handleViewException
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­Engines/­PhpEngine.php41
30. Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine handleViewException
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­Engines/­PhpEngine.php41
31. ErrorException
    …/­app/­storage/­views/­e4eb13e60cfc4ad016623c6d6306139d3
32. Illuminate\Exception\Handler handleError
    …/­app/­storage/­views/­e4eb13e60cfc4ad016623c6d6306139d3
33. include
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­Engines/­PhpEngine.php37
34. Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine evaluatePath
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­Engines/­CompilerEngine.php57
35. Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine get
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­View.php140
36. Illuminate\View\View getContents
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­View.php109
37. Illuminate\View\View renderContents
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­View.php78
38. Illuminate\View\View render
    …/­app/­storage/­views/­9acc7d9492d73fd202cf68f00687f052444
39. include
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­Engines/­PhpEngine.php37
40. Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine evaluatePath
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­Engines/­CompilerEngine.php57
41. Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine get
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­View.php140
42. Illuminate\View\View getContents
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­View.php109
43. Illuminate\View\View renderContents
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­View/­View.php78
44. Illuminate\View\View render
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Http/­Response.php43
45. Illuminate\Http\Response setContent
    …/­vendor/­symfony/­http-foundation/­Response.php202
46. Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response __construct
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Routing/­Router.php1501
47. Illuminate\Routing\Router prepareResponse
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Routing/­Router.php1036
48. Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatchToRoute
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Routing/­Router.php1001
49. Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatch
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­Application.php781
50. Illuminate\Foundation\Application dispatch
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­Application.php745
51. Illuminate\Foundation\Application handle
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Session/­Middleware.php72
52. Illuminate\Session\Middleware handle
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Cookie/­Queue.php47
53. Illuminate\Cookie\Queue handle
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Cookie/­Guard.php51
54. Illuminate\Cookie\Guard handle
    …/­vendor/­stack/­builder/­src/­Stack/­StackedHttpKernel.php23
55. Stack\StackedHttpKernel handle
    …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­Application.php641
56. Illuminate\Foundation\Application run
    …/­public/­index.php49

URL page error: http://posmg.posesa.com.br/cursos/3

```html
 <?php
$type = ($course_type == 1) ? 'pre': 'ead';
$name = Str::slug(strtolower($course->name));
$name = trim(str_replace('advocacia','',$name),'-..-');
$event = $type.'_'.$name;
?>
@if($course_type == 2)
<div id="side-with-margin">
<div class="pre-inscricao">
 <a href="{{ route('site.registrations') }}" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'botao', 'clique', '{{ $event }}');" >
  <img src="{{ Image::url('layout/inscricao-verde.png') }}" alt="" class="img-responsive-center" border="0" />
 </a>
</div>
@if( Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName() != 'site.how_it_works' )
<div class="space-30"></div>
<a href="{{ route('site.how_it_works') }}">
 <img src="{{ Image::url('layout/como-funcionam.png') }}" alt="" class="img-responsive-center" border="0" />
</a>
@endif
<div class="space-30"></div>
<a href="{{ route('site.poles') }}">
 <img src="{{ Image::url('layout/polos-ead.png') }}" alt="" class="img-responsive-center" border="0" />
</a>
<div class="space-30"></div>
<div class="carousel_right">
 @include('site.components.depoimentos',compact('testimonials'))
</div>
</div>
@else
<div class="pre-inscricao">
<a href="{{ route('site.registrations') }}" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'botao', 'clique', '{{ $event }}');" >
 <img src="{{ Image::url('layout/inscricao-verde.png') }}" alt="" class="img-responsive-center" border="0" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="space-30"></div>
<div class="carousel_right">
@include('site.components.depoimentos',compact('testimonials'))
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: é alguma busca que esta retornando sem dados, veja se não esta tentando pegar dados de um retorno vazio.
veja se esse $course->name tem algum dado ou esta retornando nada

Comment: obrigada douglas consegui resolver